# Paraview: Add axes to the planes not aligned with the Orientation axes

Tags: paraview

I have created a slice in paraview. This slice is rotated about the z axis. Hence when I use the "Axes grid" for adding the axes, the axes also appears to be rotated. If there a way to define a new axes in Paraview that aligns with the rotated slice? Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to use the Transform filter and configure it manually based on your slice Z-rotation. Not very practical I agree.